# Using OAuth token in android

Tags: android, oauth

I am using `OAuth` in My application , I am able to do authentication and  login successfully from a specific Google mail ID.

First time when I login to app It shows confirmation screen , Once I click on "OK" then It gets the token from Google.But from next time it automatically get the token from Google.But I want to show the confirmation dialog to user whenever he opens the app.
I think google account manager somewhere keeps reference of email that I have signed in before.I just want to clear that preference.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: “But from next time it automatically get the token from Google.” That's impossible. Do you mean "it can access the Google API with the token you got last time"?

Comment: No,It is giving new auth token when each every time I login via OAuth.

Comment: But some where the Email Id is getting stored .I want to release that id once I click on back button or exit out of the application.